# Cannot establish connection to Dynamics 365

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

We have Sitecore 10.0 Update 1 and on top we have installed Data Exchange Framework 5.0 and Sitecore Connect for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 5.0.0.

I have followed the installation guide on setting up both modules.

When I am trying to check connection between Sitecore and Dynamics by running Troubleshooting I get this error message:

```
Exception during connection. Read more in log file. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://obfuscated.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=9'.
```

[image]

I have this setup in ConnectionStrings.config:

```
<add name="formsCrm" connectionString="url=https://OOO.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;user id=OOO@OOO.onmicrosoft.com;password=OOO;organization=OOO;authentication type=2" />
```

I have already tried to change authentication type to 0 and 1 but no difference.

I have organization ID from Developer Resources and Unique Name:

[image]

What I have missed? Any resolution for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use DEF 5.0.0 but on previous versions I used:

```
<add name="dynamicsCRM" connectionString="Url=https://sitecoretest9.crm4.dynamics.com; User id=[my email]; Password=[my password];" />
```

Comment: Note that `ClientSecret` is the recommended authentication method at this time:`AuthType=ClientSecret;ClientId=SOME_GUID;ClientSecret=SOME_SECRET;Url=https://ORG_NAME.crm.dynamics.com/`

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on slack; the connectionstring URL has to contain crm**4**.dynamics.com, instead of crm.dynamics.com

Comment: Why does it _need_ to contain `4`? Isn't that just a Dynamics 365 CRM URL region?